# Git push from ZIP file to other server without connection to origin master

Tags: git, bash

I would like to push the files from our GIT repository to an other server, which is already working fine. However this needs to be done by someone who hasn't access to our GIT repository. So what I proposed is that I would sent him the files from the repository in a ZIP file, but how can he push those files to another server then?

1. Unzip file
2. Start GIT bash
3. git init
4. git remote add UAT ssh://username@ip_address:port
5. git fetch UAT
6. git push ??

GIT doesn't recognize the files in the repository, when I add them with

1. gitt add .
2. git commit -m "Message"

And I will try to push them then I will get a message from GIT that I need to pull the data, when I do that and call git pull -r UAT master I will get merge conflicts. All I want to achieve is that I push the data from the ZIP file to the server (and override it).

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure because this case is weird, but I think you should merge UAT/master to your local master before commit something else. (remark : `pull` = `fetch` -> `merge`, so you can do `git pull UAT master`, it should works too)

Comment: Try rebase and resolve conflicts. Then try force push.

Answer (score 0):

You would do these steps:

1. Unzip the file into a fresh folder (let's call this folder **A**)
2. Clone the original repository *in a different folder* (let's call this folder **B**)
3. Use a tool, such as ROBOCOPY on Windows, to mirror the contents of A into B, making sure to overwrite files, add new files from A to B and remove files in B that is not present in A

   - **NOTE!** Make sure to not touch the `.git` folder in this mirroring process. If you use ROBOCOPY you would add `/xd .git`
4. git add
5. git commit
6. git push

This would accomplish what you set out to do.

**NOTE!** There is a timing issue here. If someone else pushes new commits into the remote repository after you've cloned it here but before you push, you would get a push reject in step 6. If you get this then I would seriously question what you're doing since you've clearly said that the guy with the zip file is supposed to overwrite the repository, yet you're allowing others to work on the same files. This is a recipe for disaster.

---

If you're only sending this person *some* of the files, you need to modify step 3 to be this:

3. Use a tool to copy files from A into B

In this case, if the person using this cumbersome method to work is renaming or removing files you need to handle this by comparing the zip file or files you sent to him in the first place with what is currently in the archive and handle the discrepancies.